# Decorator of a nested function [Python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators, nested-function

I'm writing a simple program using threading and sockets. I have created a decorated function with some nested functions inside. They look like this:

```
class Some_class(object):

    class Decorators(object):

        @classmethod
        def some_decorator(cls, function):
            def inner_function():
                # some_decorations
                pass
            return inner_function

    def __init__(self):
        # some code
        pass

    @Decorators.some_decorator
    def function(self):

        def nested1():
            # some code
            pass

        def nested2():
            # some code
            pass
```

I've written the `nested1` and `nested2` as nested functions just because I found usefull to have some better code-organization. I have defined the `some_decorator` in a nested class inside an existing one as I saw from this link: https://medium.com/@vadimpushtaev/decorator-inside-python-class-1e74d23107f6. I tryied to decorate the nested functions as well, but I have got an error that says: `NameError: name 'Decorators' is not defined`. Are there any solutions?

Thank you very much for your time and excuse my English, I'm still practising it!

Comment: I don't get this error in Python 3.9. What version of Python are you using?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. You copied the code incomplete  but this should give an `TypeError: some_decorator() missing 1 required positional argument: 'function'` because you didn't declare your decorater `@classmethod`.

Comment: I'm using python 3.7.9. Actually in my code I've included @classmethod decorator, I've just forgot to include it in here

Comment: With `@classmethod` your example code runs without an error.

Comment: Yes but in the question I was asking how to add the decorator `@Decorators.some_decorator` to the inner funtions `inner1` and `inner2`. This because when I try to add it I get the error I was talking about in the question

Comment: Why didn't you include this in your code? And: No error when you decorate the inner functions with `@Decorators.some_decorator`. I can't find `inner1` or `inner2`, but no error with `nested1` or `nested2`.